# Sending Bulk Email Async Without violating Limits Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, architecture, jakarta-mail

I have to send bulk email through java SMTP. Currently I send email synchronously which is taking a lot of time and since every email provider have their per hour limit, so I have to sleep thread to avoid limitation.

What will be the best **approach** to send email Asynchronously without violating limitation using SMTP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use your own SMTP server, or pay for one with no limits.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to send mails asynchronously running a new thread or using executor service.

But since you need capability to throttle outgoing mails you need a store and forward mechanism. Ideal solution would be using a queue where mesages can be posted. And then there should be a queue consumer which will be responsible for reading from the queue and sending the actual mail.